# Apache RewriteEngine - Rewrite anything that not exists to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2.4

I'm really struggling now.
First of all, i searched on Google and here, and none of the solutions found worked for me. I don't really have much time right now to completely dig into Apache docs for solid understanding of the RewriteEngine(will do later for sure).

**WHAT I NEED**
I need to handle special requests from our Google Adwords campaign, which look like this: http://website.com/something/%first_param%/%second_param%/%third_param%
In my document root directory, i have *index.php* where i parse the query string using regex and acquire these parameters, like this:
`$request_URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`
`preg_match('/\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)/', $request_URI, $matches);`
**THE PROBLEM**
Apache successfully redirects everything, but it also includes all additional requests for all the resources, so instead of fetching resources it just gets me the same index.php.
Currently i have this *.htaccess* file in my document root:
        `RewriteEngine on`
        `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
        `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
        `RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]`
Please note, that i am using Virtual Host for this project:
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
    `ServerName masuma.hyperauto.local`
    `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/projects/masuma landing"`
`</VirtualHost>`
I have my *index.php* in this root directory above.
I have also enabled RewriteEngine logs and found interesting things here, but i still can't solve this:

```
add path info postfix: C:/wamp64/www/projects/masuma landing/test -> C:/wamp64/www/projects/masuma landing/test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css, referer: host_here/test/test/firm/toyota
strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp64/www/projects/masuma landing/test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css -> test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css, referer: host_here/test/test/firm/toyota
applying pattern '.*' to uri 'test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css', referer: host_here/test/test/firm/toyota
rewrite 'test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css' -> 'index.php?url=test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css', referer: host_here/test/test/firm/toyota
split uri=index.php?url=test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css -> uri=index.php, args=url=test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css, referer: host_here/test/test/firm/toyota <br><br>
```

I can see here, that it prepends the path in query string to the resource filename, like *test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css*, but the resources are in the document root!
**UPD: SOLUTION**
The flag `[DPI]` in my `RewriteRule` solved the problem.
Now the rule looks like `RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L,DPI]`
And, what is important, i am still able to get the original query path in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: If Apache rewrites successfully to index.php, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `RewriteCond`s checks incoming file/folder paths for non-existence and then redirects to index.php. Clarify the "all additional requests for all the resources".

Comment: it compose non exsistent `C:/wamp64/www/projects/masuma landing/test/test/firm/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @Deadooshka i want it to fetch the resources relative to document root, but if the request URI is, like, *host_name/anything/something*, then links become *anything/something/style.css*, when should be *host_name/style.css*

Comment: also consider to turn off the [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just need the `[DPI]` flag on your RewriteRule to get rid of the calculated PATH_INFO?

Comment: thank you very much, seems like everything works now and i'm still able to get the original query path in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']